# jQuery show hide delay still running after mouse is away

Tags: javascript, jquery

I set .delay() to stop showing on every mouse over the effect but now it is showing on every mouse over just delayed.

Seems .delay() is not the correct way to recognize the mouse over for a minimum time to show after the section.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.article_wrapper').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find('.actions').delay(800).show(300);
    },
    function(){
         $(this).find('.actions').hide(200);
    });

});
```

Which other Functions can I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>On jQuery 1.9+, you can use [finish()](http://api.jquery.com/finish/) to clear all previous delay applied to specific queue:
***(although this is still undocumented)***</strike>

### DEMO

**UPDATE:** *indeed, to not break hide animation, you should use `clearQueue()`*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.article_wrapper').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find('.actions').delay(800).show(300);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('.actions').clearQueue().hide(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: If there is no animation chaining, using `.stop(true,true)` is sufficient but `.finish()` is future-proof (in the event that you are adding more animations).

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately a slightly annoying issue. The correct way of solving this is with "setTimeout", explained in greater detail here. [Trying to add delay to jQuery AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308404/trying-to-add-delay-to-jquery-ajax-request)

This can easily be modified for your needs.

**Edit**

As the better answer pointed out, this isn't neccessary for animations, I'll leave it here because it is relevant to most non-animation delays.

Comment: I would not use `setTimeout`, because its implementation is more complicated than using a simple `.finish()` or `.stop()`.

Comment: I completely agree, A. Wolff has a significantly better answer.